# Change size of icon type in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, desktop-customization

Windows view has LIST TYPE. Is there any way to change the icon size for those views?

For example, I want to explore in LIST VIEW but I want the icon a little bit larger.
[image]

In the above image can I make the Camera Roll icon bigger without changing the View type(List)

Answer (score 2):

The size of the Windows Explorer Ribbon and Icons within the Ribbon is fixed within Explorer and cannot be changed relative to Windows  Explorer.

If you wish to make the entire view of Explorer larger, you can use the Scaling factor in Windows 10 (Start, System, Display).

> I want explore in LIST VIEW but i want icon a little bit larger.

You can do this only by the Scaling factor and not individually.

Comment: I did not want to chagne resolution or scaling factor. It will change my requirement. I want all element small but big list view icon, Even I am okay to have all view icon little bigger

Comment: You cannot do that. As I noted in my Answer, the Ribbon Size and related Icon Size is fixed within Windows Explorer.

Comment: The Small Icons, List, and Details view modes all us icons from the small system image list. All icons in an image list must be the same size. The size is determined by the scaling factor.